# selenium don't recognize objects via eclipse

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am using eclipse for selenium web driver. My scripts identify some objects and than stop identifying objects, I am getting error "Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"AddMoreButton"}". Earlier my scripts were working fine but they are giving this error now. Please tell me the checkpoints which i can check..

Comment: Check whether the element you are accessing, is loaded on page. Before this check that you are using correct identifier for the element. If you add required html, we will be able to help you better.

Comment: Check the application whether it is having the same element in DOM.

Comment: Sometime it picks up the object and sometime does not. The same script is working fine on my friends machine

Comment: Number of things that come to mind: it sometimes works and sometimes doesn't -> then you should implement waiting for things to appear on the page. You should also check your versions of Firefox/Chrome/IE and Selenium.